# how do i fix a discord.py bot member join dm not sending

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a bot for a server im in and I was having the bot send a dm to every new member that join but it does not work

here is my the code im struggling with:

```
@bot.event   
async def on_member_join(member):
  await member.send('welcome to **SHADE WARS** *!* **__nitro__** hunger games, **__shade__**, and more. <:emoji_32:1137857351756562473>  \n   <:giselle:1137728420176986152>  ***make sure to read rules before speaking***')
  await member.send("https://tenor.com/bhXRq.gif")
```

I expected that once a member joins the bot would send two messages to said members dms. One being a welcome message and the other being a gif

Comment: Have you enabled `intents.menbers`?